# No Cone of Influence Displayed Using WaveletComp in R

Tags: r

I am using the `WaveletComp` package in R. I first run `analyze.coherency` to get the cross-wavelet transform and store the result in my.`wc`.

Next, I want to get a figure of the cross-wavelet power levels and apply `wc.image` to the previously stored results. The figure is plotted but missing the cone of influence. I did not change the default setting (which is to display the cone of influence). Even explicitly providing the argument for inclusion of the cone of influence does not work.

Did anyone experience similar issues and is there any advice how to fix this issue? Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It would be helpful if you added your code and current output as well as an example of your desired output.

Answer (score -1):

Many thanks, I figured out the issue: The cone of influence is not displayed in the plot window. Only saving the graphic as svg or pdf file will show the cone of influence. All other file extensions won't do the job.